# Stack, shuffle and get back the original tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have following two tensorflow placeholders:

```
Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(32, 2048), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Placeholder:1", shape=(64, 2048), dtype=float32)
```

Let's call them `a` and `b`. I want to `stack` them and then `shuffle` randomly. Afterwards, I want to pass them through network. Finally, I want to get the back the `a` and `b` before `stack` and `shuffle`

**What I have done so far**

I understand [stacking](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) and random [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56575877/shuffling-two-tensors-in-the-same-order).
Therefore, guide me how I can stack them, shuffle them, and finally get back the original indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `shuffle index` on the concatenated matrix, so that we know the elements that got shuffled went where and then we can put together back in order using `argsort` of the indices.

Inputs:

```
a = tf.random.normal(shape=(32, 2048), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.random.normal(shape=(64, 2048), dtype=tf.float32)
```

Stack the arrays:

```
c = tf.concat([a,b], axis=0)
```

Random shuffle:

```
indices = tf.range(start=0, limit=tf.shape(c)[0], dtype=tf.int32)
shuffled_indices = tf.random.shuffle(indices) #shuffled index will tell where each element of c went.
shuffled_c = tf.gather(c, shuffled_indices)
```

Get back `c, a, b`:

```
getback_c = tf.gather(shuffled_c, tf.argsort(shuffled_indices))
a_1, b_1 = getback_c[:tf.shape(a)[0]], getback_c[tf.shape(a)[0]:]
```

Verify the values are same:

```
np.testing.assert_allclose(a.numpy(), a_1.numpy())
np.testing.assert_allclose(b.numpy(), b_1.numpy())
```

Comment: how we can place them one after the other?